# Converting timestamp in seconds to a date format in R

Tags: r, date, timestamp, strptime

I have a table (tags) with a column for timestamp (ts), which is formatted as seconds since 1 Jan, 1970 GMT. I'm trying to create a date column that converts the timestamp from seconds to date and time EST.

The suggested code for R was:

```
tags$date<-strptime(tags$ts, "%Y-%m-%d")
tags$date<-as.POSIXct(tags$date)
```

But when I do this, `tags$date` comes up as NA. Any suggestions for what I might be doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. please read [how to write a good R question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/3250126). Use `dput(head(tags))` to share a sample of your data.

Comment: Also please review [mcve].

Answer (score 4):

You should us `as.POSIXct` function instead:

```
tags$date <- as.POSIXct(tags$ts, origin="1970-01-01", tz="US/New York")
```

`strptime` converts between character representations and dates not between timestamp and dates.

Comment: Also required the time in timezone EST so would be something like tags$date <- as.POSIXct(tags$ts, origin="1970-01-01", tz="US/New York")

Comment: You're right I forgot the timezone. Just edited my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `lubridate` version. When we use `as_datetime` we don't need to explicitly specify an origin as it defaults to the desired origin.

```
lubridate::as_datetime(1507119276, tz='EST')
# [1] "2017-10-04 07:14:36 EST"
```